# PORT 80 all of a sudden not working when calling with twilio

Tags: python, flask, server, twilio

I am trying to run a small program using twilio and the digitalocean server.  This is the code:

```
from flask import Flask, request
from twilio.twiml.messaging_response import MessagingResponse
from twilio.rest import Client
account_sid = 'xxxxx'
auth_token = 'xxxxx'
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/sms", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def sms_ahoy_reply():
    body = request.values.get('Body', None)
    resp = MessagingResponse()
    body=" Question: "+body
    message = client.messages \
                    .create(
                         body=body,
                         from_='xxx',
                         to='xxxx'
                     )
    print(message.sid)
    # Add a message
    resp.message("Thank you for your question")
    return str(resp)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print ("under the main")
    #app.run(debug=True)
    app.run(host="198.211.101.234", port=80, debug=True)
```

The program uses flask to handle get and post requests and then return a message. The message will be send to the server port 80 (198.211.101.234). I've tried this several times before and it was working. However, when I tried it again this weekend, I got an error. The main function sms_ahoy_reply was not called when a message is sent to the server. Twilio told me that they have received a HTTP retrieval failure error. In addition, 198.211.101.234/sms doesnt seem to be working either. I've tried the exact same code on a ngrok server and it worked well. So it is not a twilio or code error at this point. I also tred to ping in from local machine and got this error :

```
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
Request timeout for icmp_seq 3
Request timeout for icmp_seq 4
Request timeout for icmp_seq 5
Request timeout for icmp_seq 6
Request timeout for icmp_seq 7
Request timeout for icmp_seq 8
92 bytes from 10.10.16.250: Redirect Host(New addr: 10.10.16.1)
Vr HL TOS Len ID Flg off TTL Pro cks Src Dst
```

So it has timeout most of the time but sometimes it responds

Comment: Sounds like it's something to do with the way you are running your flask app. Is it crashing or just shutting down for any reason? How are you starting the application?

Comment: hi thanks for replying! I later found out about the problem.. i forget to put port 80 on the firewall..Thanks for the help though

Comment: Glad you got it sorted!